# Mathematical Formulation of the magnetic field $B$

Tags: electromagnetism, work, conservative-field

I have a question about the mathematical formulation of the magnetic field $B$.
First, i will just recapitulate some properties of vector calculus.
If $ \vec{F} $ is a vector field, then $\vec{F}$ will be conservative if:

$$\oint_c \vec{F}d\vec{r} = 0 $$
for every $c$ (closed-curve). and if
$${\int_{a}^{b}}_C \vec{F}d\vec{r} $$ is path-independent.

So i believe both these properties apply for $B$, because $W_{a\rightarrow b} = 0$, not depending on the path, and the $W$ in an closed path will always be also $0$.
But here is the point: We define $\psi$ as the "scalar magnetic potential". So it is quite obvious that $\nabla \psi = B$ (or $-\nabla \psi = B $, in this case). But if the work on any path of $B$ is always $0$, and since the work for conservative fields is final potential $-$ initial potential, does that mean that $\psi$ is the same everywhere? 
If it does not, it's quite confusing, since there it would be work for some path where $\psi_{final}$ is different from $\psi_{initial}$. If it does, it's quite confusing because: What is the point of defining an scalar field that its the same everywhere?

I understand the part that $B$ wont do any work because its always perpendicular to motion. But is the mathematical explanation from vector calculus that i can't comprehend.

Comment: The magnetic flux density $\vec B$ isn't generally zero if you integrate it around a closed contour. [Ask Ampère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re's_circuital_law). In cases where you *can* define a magnetic scalar potential, it makes roughly the same sense as the electric scalar potential. Work by the force field can be inferred from change in the potential (energy), but this doesn't mean that the potential is constant.

Comment: No. But what about the work?

Comment: What abou​t it?

Comment: I think you're confusing the idea of a conservative vector field with the idea of a conservative force. Note that the force due to $B$ fields is not in the direction of the $B$ field.

Comment: Yes, Daniel. I believe that this is exactly the point that is confusing me...